# Lottie how to run arbritary code inbetween two segments?

Tags: javascript, lottie

Let's say I've defined a lottie animation using `var anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation({<anim data here>})`

Now, what i wanna do is something like:

```js
anim.playSegments([80,101]);
console.log("example");
anim.playSegments([102,121]);
```

The problem here is that `console.log` is not waiting for the first segment to end in order to run. It runs as soon as the first segment starts.

I understand this due to javascript being synchronous, but is there a way to run this asynchronously? In other words, **is there a way for the console.log to wait for the first segment to finish before running?**
Play segment -> do something -> play another segment

---

### Things that I've tried:

```js
anim.playSegments([80,101]).then(() => {
    console.log("test")
});
anim.playSegments([102,121]);
```

didn't work. Returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

```js
 anim.playSegments([80,101])
 anim.onComplete = function() {
     console.log("Test")
 }
 anim.playSegments([102,121]);
```

This will run the `console.log()` after the **second** segment is complete.

```js
anim.playSegments([80,101])
anim.onComplete = function() {
    console.log("frame!");
    anim.playSegments([102,121]);
}
```

this will keep looping the second segment, since it plays it again once it's complete.